# How to add new object attribute with Python/Django

Tags: python, django

**Full Disclosure:** I'm just learning Django

The homepage of our site is displaying recent blog posts. In `views.py` there is a class that defines the attributes that can be called using `post.get_attribute` to call the recent posts on the homepage. I am trying to add a new attribute that is in the model `featured_image` but am not able to get it to render on the homepage.

```
# From models.py
featured_image = models.ImageField(_('featured image'), 
                                    upload_to='images/posts', 
                                    blank=True, null=True)

# Added featured_image to class in views.py
def get_posts(request, post_type):
    if post_type == 'personal':
        posts = list(Post.personal_objects.all().values('title', 'slug',
                                                       'author__username',
                                                       'views', 
                                                       'featured_image'))[:8]
    elif post_type == 'business':
        posts = list(Post.business_objects.all().values('title', 'slug', 
                                                        'author__username',  
                                                        'views', 
                                                        'featured_image'))[:8]
    else:
        raise Http404
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(posts), mimetype='application/json')
```

How I am trying to call the featured image in `home.html`:

```
<a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
    <img src="{{ post.get_featured_image_url }}" />
</a>
```

What am I missing to get these images pulling in? Really appreciate any insight. For broader context visit [this link.](http://dev.knowyourbank.com?python4life)

Comment: Please take the effort to indent your code correctly?

Comment: Poor indentation in Python code is a big no-no ;)

Comment: Formatted wrong when I posted question, will do it right next time.

Comment: sorry, my bad. dunno how it went past community review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the images in your template by calling the model field

```
{{ post.featured_image }}
```